# Representing Modbus data using Timeseries

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

Is it possible to represent Modbus data in a time series format using Python for example? I would like to see how Modbus data changes over time using time series. Do you think this is useful anyway or it depends on what you are looking for behind this representation?

I am not expert of Fieldbus protocols. I am just looking for your opinions.

Comment: Modbus is a data communications protocol; it enables you to retrieve data over a serial (or TCP) link; what you do with the data is up to you. Storing and analysing the retrieved data is a pretty common use-case. Not really sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Thank you for that. I got it. My question is how I can represent modus data using timeseries?

Comment: Modbus is just a protocol that you can use to acquire data so "modbus data" has little meaning. The data available varies depending upon the device and many devices will just give you their current state (for example a weather station might make the current temperature, wind speed and wind direction available). This means that you will probably need to poll the device over a period of time in order to build up your time series.